# Использование ссылки на метод класса (.attribute)

Tags: python, классы, методы, атрибуты

Недавно я просматривал код создания змейки на Python с помощью tkinter. Есть класс сегментов змейки, в котором проинициализирован атрибут который содержит в себе создание прямоугольника. Но в дальнейшем этот атрибут был использован через .instance. Я не понимаю зачем это делается и если можно, подробно объяснить весь процесс, что происходит для чайника. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай отправлю ссылку на статью.
http://pythonicway.com/python-games/python-arcade/18-python-snake

Comment: Да, непонятно, почему `instance`, а не `rectangle` назвали поле.

Comment: ну назвали переменную `instance` поэтому к ней так и обращаются. название переменной ведь не влияет на работу программы (за исключением наименований переменных зарезервированными именами)